# My music player is stop play music when i load my application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio-player

I am doing alarm based application in which my application is being prevent from deep sleep and fire local notification when time is comes up.For Prevent deep sleep i am using the [mmpdeepsleeppreventer](https://github.com/marcop/iPhoneInsomnia) but it raise one problem in my application.**When any one play music in music player and start my application then music player stop play music**.How can i over come from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because audio session initialization in MMPDeepSleepPreventer.m in `- (void)mmp_setUpAudioSession` it uses audio session category kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback.

Look for this Apple docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/index.html
"This category normally prevents audio from other apps from mixing with your app's audio. To allow mixing for this category, use the kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers property."

Try to set audion session property kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers

Comment: btw this is deprecated audio session methods. Maybe you should look for proper solution to prevent your app from deep sleep.

Comment: @max_norb thanks for your answer i already used it in audio session.